# My Ruby files don't run correctly

Tags: ruby

When i click on a .rb file to run it a CMD window pops up for a brief second and then closes again. This is probably a really nooby question thats easily fixed but i've looked everywhere for help. But like i said it pops up for a brief second and i THINK while its up its executing the code but when the codes done it closes so i don't know if i'm making mistakes in code or other important things like that.

Answer (score 4):

Run the program through the command prompt (CMD), that way you can see the result, otherwise the window closes when the program exits.

---

Alternatively, you can prevent the program from exiting by putting some sort of blocking instruction at the end of the script, such that the program waits for user input before exiting.

Comment: but when i run it in the prompt it says "hello.rb is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file."

Comment: You need to pass 'hello.rb' in as an argument to the ruby interpreter. Assuming ruby is in the PATH (it should be, but not having used ruby on windows for a long time, I could be wrong), the command should simply be 'ruby hello.rb'.

Comment: for that it says "ruby: No such file or directory -- hello.rb

Comment: thats the problem i have the file hello.rb asks for the users name and then puts "Hello" + name. but even when i just click the program it still flashes for a brief second

Comment: Are you in the same directory as the hello.rb when you try to launch it? If you run `dir` in the cmd prompt, do you see it? If not, you will have to use `cd` to navigate to the same directory (or give the full relative path in your command). See this [link](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos126/cmd-prompt.html) on how to change directories and work with the command prompt.

Comment: thank you for helping i got it now :D! and sorry for my absolute noobery.

Comment: @Divide: No problem, any time. And no need to apologize, everyone starts off as a noob, "The only 'intuitive' interface is the nipple, after that everything is learned" - Bruce Ediger

Answer (score 0):

Press Windows_Key+R and then type CMD.  Browse to the location of the file and then type ruby your_ruby_file.rb.  The program is running, but Windows automatically closes the window upon completion of the command.

Comment: i don't know what you mean by browse to the location. do you mean in the CMD window or just go there with like My Computer>C:>Program Files>Ruby187>Projects>hello.rb?

Comment: Go there in the CMD window.  Type cd \"Program Files"\Ruby187\Projects then press enter.  Then type ruby hello.rb and enter.

Answer (score 0):

To get Windows to run your *.rb files through Ruby when you click on them in the UI, you have to associate the `.rb` extension with the `ruby.exe` executable. Such an association is called a "Windows File Association." Here's a Microsoft Knowledge Base article that'll tell you how to create such a thing.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859